# How to reset/remove added filters 'posts_join' and 'posts_orderby' after the loop is completed?

Tags: wordpress, filter

I am sorting results appear on the category archive page using these filters: `posts_join` and  `posts_orderby`. There is a widget, which displays recent posts. I am using default recent posts widget of WordPress. But it's not showing any result. When I investigated I found that the applied filters are getting applied to this query. So, I tried remove the filters using the following code:

```
remove_filter('posts_join', 'my_filter_join');
remove_filter('posts_orderby', 'my_filter_orderby');
```

But still it does not work.

I also tried to put the following code in the filter functions itself:

```
// Disable this filter for future queries!
remove_filter(current_filter(), __FUNCTION__);
```

It does not work either.

How to fix this issue?

Comment: did you reset your query after modifying it and removing the filters  ?? `wp_reset_postdata()`
`wp_reset_query()` or `rewind_posts()`

Comment: I have used `wp_reset_postdata()` and `wp_reset_query()` before, but it did not solve the issue. I don't think `rewind_posts()` could solve the issue, but I also tried this. Does not make any change!